# How to find the common values for a column which is present in many tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a lot of tables in oracle DB. All tables have one common column named as  'COLUMN_FILTER' .All tables have lots of unique values for 'COLUMN_FILTER'. Is there any way to find the common records for 'COLUMN_FILTER' , present in all tables ? For sample please refer to the below scenario, where I have provided unique values for 'COLUMN_FILTER'.

```
     Table A: 'X','Y','Z'
     Table B: 'W','X'
     Table C: 'Z'
     Table D: 'Y','Z'
```

I am expecting the output to be 'Z','W' (any possible minimum set). So that I can put this filter on all tables.

Comment: In the example Z is common 3 out of 4 tables and W is available only in 1 out of 4 tables. Could you tell us how you arrived that Z,W combination

Comment: @pythonlearner . . . What version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Use `HAVING COUNT(*)>1` clause along with `GROUP`ing `BY` that column

```
SELECT column_filter
  FROM
  (
  SELECT column_filter FROM tableA
  UNION ALL
  SELECT column_filter FROM tableB
  UNION ALL
  SELECT column_filter FROM tableC
  UNION ALL
  SELECT column_filter FROM tableD
  )
 GROUP BY column_filter
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

To find out the most common element you could have a query as follows
The highest value of cnt_vals indicate the tables which has the most common values of common_filter across all tables

```
select table_name
      ,column_filter
      ,count(column_filter) over(partition by 1) as cnt_vals
  from (
        select distinct column_filter,'A' as table_name
          from tablea
        union all
        select distinct column_filter,'B' as table_name
          from tableb
        union all
        select distinct column_filter,'C' as table_name
          from tablec
        union all
        select distinct column_filter,'D' as table_name
          from tabled
      )x
order by 3 desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find *pairs* using a join:

```
with f as (
      select distinct column_filter, 'A' as table_name
      from tablea
      union all
      select distinct column_filter, 'B' as table_name
      from tableb
      union all
      select distinct column_filter, 'C' as table_name
      from tablec
      union all
      select distinct column_filter, 'D' as table_name
      from tabled
     )
select f1.column_filter, f2.column_filter
from f f1 join
     f f2
     on f1.column_filter < f2.column_filter
group by f1.column_filter, f2.column_filter
having sum(case when 'A' in (f1.table_name, f2.table_name) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when 'B' in (f1.table_name, f2.table_name) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when 'C' in (f1.table_name, f2.table_name) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when 'D' in (f1.table_name, f2.table_name) then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

You can easily extend this for triples:

```
with f as (
      select distinct column_filter, 'A' as table_name
      from tablea
      union all
      select distinct column_filter, 'B' as table_name
      from tableb
      union all
      select distinct column_filter, 'C' as table_name
      from tablec
      union all
      select distinct column_filter, 'D' as table_name
      from tabled
     )
select f1.column_filter, f2.column_filter
from f f1 join
     f f2
     on f1.column_filter < f2.column_filter join
     f f3
     on f3.column_filter < f2.column_filter
group by f1.column_filter, f2.column_filter, fd.column_filter
having sum(case when 'A' in (f1.table_name, f2.table_name, f3.table_name) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when 'B' in (f1.table_name, f2.table_name, f3.table_name) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when 'C' in (f1.table_name, f2.table_name, f3.table_name) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when 'D' in (f1.table_name, f2.table_name, f3.table_name) then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

It is possible to express this as a recursive query, if you don't want to try more and more combinations.  In Oracle 12C+, I would recommend a recursive CTE.  In earlier versions, you have to adapt using `connect by`.